# Send IPad App for review every x days ( continuous deploy )

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store

Hy guys,

I've already search after this kind of management and come out with nothing.

Let's assume i have an IPad App currently in version 1.0.0 and i send that for review today (11/24/2014).

In 2-3 days (11/28/2014) i want to push live a quick fix so i must send my IPad App again (1.0.1).

How can i accomplish something like continuous deploying my app ?

What's happening if i already have a version in review and i send another and what's the correct approach for this scenario?

[I know that the application must be tested before going live, but i have encountered this scenario dealing with a client asking for a quick fix as soon as possible]

Thanks,
Razvan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set you CI server to build for deployment and connect this to iTunes Connect. If you have a new build (1.0.1) you cannot just swap the binaries, you will have to self reject 1.0.0 and prepare for binary on iTunes Connect for 1.0.1. This could be done programatically but it's not a common practice. I would tell the client to come up with a workable release plan where bug fixes and changes get submitted let's say every Friday. Trying to automate what your require is no mean task and as I say, not very many people have the patience to set this up. Just setting up Jenkins is tough enough for most people.

Comment: I see. Thanks for that. Now I have 1.0.0 in review status & I want to send 1.0.1 to review. I must self reject 1.0.0 and then submit the 1.0.1 ?

Comment: No just create a new version on iTunes connect for 1.0.1 (you don't have to fill out all of the meta data just the whats changed bit. That means if 1.0.0 is released you can replace it with 1.0.1 as it becomes approved. If you reject 1.0.0 for 1.0.1 you go to the back of the queue.

Comment: Great, this make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't continuous deploy to the iOS App store on a cycle that is a small number of days, since Apple's App store review time is variable from hours to multiple weeks, is unknown at submission time (as Apple very often finishes reviews greatly out-of-order from submission order), and you can't have more than one version of the same app fully submitted for review at any one time.  Rejecting a submission to submit a newer update for review will push your app to the start of the (potentially weeks long) queue again.

Apple (during one of their past Tech Talks) has recommended submitting new updates only around once per month, unless you find critical bugs that require a more urgent update.  So you could continuous deploy at a once (or twice, as Facebook seems to try) per month rate.

As for needed quick fixes, you can request an expedited review, but Apple is reported to only react (if at all) to one or two expedite request per year per developer (or per app?).  So it's best practice to test apps well enough, before submission, to reduce the risk of needing a expedite request to well below that frequency (or suffer a week or two of bad reviews from a broken app while Apple seems to ignores your expedite request).